# What's the best way to store an id in local?

Tags: android, file, save

I'm coding an Android application. I need to store the id of a user in local in order that he doesn't have to rewrite its name, surname and password every time he uses the application.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: shared preference

Comment: use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: thank you, I'll search some documentation about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use Shared Preferences to store id**

> Code to save value

```
 public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

 SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("id", 1);
      /*editor.putString("Key", value); */
        editor.commit();
```

> Code to get value

```
 String id = sharedpreferences.getString("id", "");
/*sharedpreferences.getString("key", "defaultValue"); */
```

> 

### Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you @sukhbir it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use Shared Preference;

Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

**There are 4 ways**
**Some of the below methods are useful if you want to save more complex data.**

## 1.Shared Preferences-best for your use case

[Find the tutorial here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

## 2.SQLite-a database used for android

[Check this tutorial to get through SQLite](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite)

## 3.Content providers, if you want to share the same local data to other applications of your choice

[Find the tutorial here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm)

## 4.ORM mapping libraries

#### a.GreenDao

my favorite-[Documentation and HowToDo](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation)

#### b.DBFlow

little complex but fast-[Documentation and HowToDo](https://guides.codepath.com/android/DBFlow-Guide)

#### c.ORMLite

Very good documentation and support over the internet-[Documentation and How to do](http://ormlite.com)

#### d.Realm

New but heavily used by tech giants-[Documentation and how to do](https://realm.io/docs)

Comment: Kindly give a valid reason before down voting any post. People are trying to help here. Thanks :)