# Sharedpreferences android studio error saving data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I saved my data from an numberDecimal edit text using sharedpreference. When I want to get that data in another activity, it always appears as null, so it wasn't saved correctly. Any suggestion?

This is my code from where I save the data :

```
public void Start(View view) {
    EditText LevelEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_LevelCurrent);
    String User_Level = LevelEdit.getText().toString();
    if (User_Level == "") {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Select a level",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {


        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(GameConstants.StringvalueOfLevel,User_Level);
        editor.commit();


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Mygame_Menu.this, Mygame.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see this link how to save and get data from  `SharedPreferences` https://stackoverflow.com/a/43805317/4097793

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765921/spinner-with-sharedpreferences/49766781#49766781

Answer (score 1):

i think your condition is wrong and because of that your saving null object in shared preference don't check the string like this  `if (User_Level == "")`the == operator dose not work on the strings in java ! you should use equals method for comparing to String like this `"Amir".equals("Amir")`

use this instead `if (User_Level==null||User_Level.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to put `sharedPreference` name as parameter causes `error`.

Instead of this

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
```

Change

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferenceName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
```

Comment: I get compile error: method getPreferences in class Activity cannot be applied to given types;
required: int
found: String,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: use getApplicationContext() when calling getPreferences("",);

Comment: check out my answer again

Comment: what should I write instead of "sharedPreference" ? GameConstants.StringvalueOfLevel or User_Level?

Comment: sharedPreference is the name of your sharedPreference it's like as table name in database

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare string value with `int` format in `if` loop. Change

```
if(User_Level == "")
```

**To**

```
if(User_Level.equals(""))
```

So it will check the condition as correct. Otherwise above will execute else part even if its null.

**EDITED**

```
 private static final String PREFS_NAME = "PREF_LEVEL_DATA";
 private static final String PREFS_KEY = "LEVEL";

 public void SaveLevel(Context context, String level) {

    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(PREFS_KEY, level);

    editor.commit();
}

public String RetrieveLevel(Context context) {

    String level;
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.contains(PREFS_KEY)) {
        level = settings.getString(PREFS_KEY, "");
    } else {
        return "";
    }
    return level;
}
```

For store a value

```
SaveLevel(getApplicationContext(), User_Level);
```

For retreive a value

```
String level = RetreiveLevel(getApplicationContext());
```

**UPDATED**

```
 EditText LevelEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_LevelCurrent);
 String User_Level = LevelEdit.getText().toString();
 if (User_Level.equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Select a level",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } else {


    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("ANY_PREFERENCE_NAME",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Replace "ANY_PREFERENCE_NAME" as your own string
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString(GameConstants.StringvalueOfLevel,User_Level);
    editor.commit();


    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Mygame_Menu.this, Mygame.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but still the data is not saved

Comment: Update how you retrieve the data. And also use preference name. See my edits.

Comment: What I write instead of PREFS_NAME, the name of where i save the data or the name of the string i want to save ? ( it returns error by the SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: PREFS_NAME & PREFS_KEY both are string value. You can replace with your own. You can use same PREFS_NAME for storing mutiple values. And PREFS_KEY is unique for refrence to your storing value.

Comment: PREFS_NAME is the shared preference name where your values are stored in local preferences. You can create n no of preferences names to seperate your groups of data.  In single PREFS_NAME you can stored n no of Values with the refrence help of PREFS_KEY.

Comment: So instead of PREFS_NAME I must write GameConstants.StringvalueOfLevel or User_Level ?

Comment: See my edited & updated part in answer will help you to clear.

Comment: It worked. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Welcome glad to help..! Happy Coding :)